# What is the difference between CPA and IND-CPA?

Tags: cryptanalysis, reference-request, chosen-plaintext-attack, terminology, security-definition

I am writing a paper and I got comments from the reviewer that I don’t really understand.

Is there any difference between a CPA (Chosen Plaintext Attack) and IND-CPA (Indistinguishability under Chosen Plaintext Attack) when evaluating the security of an encryption scheme?

Comment: IND-CPA means you "survive" a CPA. CPA by itself is no security notion but an adversary model. "CPA-secure" usually refers to IND-CPA.

Answer (score 4):

IND-CPA is equivalent to `semantic security` under CPA.